# SQL query to track non openers in the last 90 days (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

Wondering if anyone would be able to help me. I need to build an sql query in Marketing Cloud that allows us to track anyone who hasn't opened an email within the last 90 days.

We have tried to use the measures function within Marketing Cloud but it doesn't seem to be accurate.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, so others can easily identify that this question has been answered correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you just like to have the subscribers that haven't opened (or received) an email in the last 90 days you can use a simple SQL utilizing the "Subscribers" and "Open" data views.

However, if you just want to select the subscribers that did receive an email, but didn't open it, you need to also use the "Sent" data view.

An example that should lead you in the right direction could look like this:

```sql
SELECT
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.EmailAddress
FROM
    [_Subscribers] s
WHERE
    s.SubscriberID NOT IN (
        SELECT o.SubscriberID FROM [_Open] o WHERE EventDate > dateadd(d,-90,getdate())
)
```

**Helpful resources:**

- [Marketing Cloud Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5)
- [Example Query: Opens in Last 30 Days](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_opens_in_last_30_days_ref.htm&type=5)